How to get the root directory of my app in google app engine?
I want to point to an file in my deployed app from different source files. For that reason it would be useful to know the root path to my app but I didn't find any env variable.

Which language? Is this Standard or Flex Environment?

In Google App Engine, there isn’t a direct environment variable that provides the root directory of your app. However, you can get the root directory of your deployed app in several ways depending on the runtime you're using
Python example:
import os
root_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

